# Export variable that is named via another variable out of a function

Tags: r

Given this sample code,

```
gene_expression<-function(gene) {
assign((paste0(gene,"_graph")),5)
}
```

an input of "ACTB" should create a variable that is named "ACTB_graph" and have a value of 5. I would like to be able to export this variable and value out of the function to store for later analysis.

I've tried various permutations of the global operator (<<-) but can't seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `assign` in a user-defined function, you need to add `envr = .GlobalEnv`. (Also, need to adjust your parentheses)

```
gene_expression <- function(gene) {
  assign(paste0(gene,"_graph"), 5, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

gene_expression("ACTB")
```

This will store it as an object in the global environment, just like `ACTB_graph <- 5` would do.